# Output of Sift Descriptors

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction, sift

In Lowe's Implementation of sift it has a

[image, descriptors, locs] = sift('1.pgm'); where 1.pgm is the image

I have an output of

```
         descriptors 199x128 double
         image 250x250 unit8
         locs 199x4 double
```

Question

1.) are the descriptors the feature vectors?

2.) if i want to write those feature vectors to a .txt file then how should i proceed?(OpenCV is accepted but Matlab is preferred )

3.) what are locs for in lowes code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [sift function documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/22212/versions/1/previews/sift.m/index.html):

1.The descriptors are K-by-128 matrix, where each row is a descriptor for one of the K keypoints.  The descriptor is a vector of 128 values normalized to unit length.

2.You can save the descriptors by using [dlmwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) function as follows:

```
dlmwrite('descriptorsFile.txt',descriptors)
```

3.locs: K-by-4 matrix. Each row has the 4 values for: row, column, scale, orientation (in the range of -PI to PI).

Comment: Thanks 

I will add this just in case anybody needs further clarrifications in item number 1

The SIFT descriptor vector is a feature vector. "Descriptor vector" and "feature vector" are synonyms in this context. Most of the descriptions of SIFT I've seen use the phrase "descriptor vector", but occasionally they'll refer to it as a "feature vector" or refer it to as "SIFT features",[Difference between Descriptor,Feature Vectors](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51373/what-is-the-difference-between-features-and-descriptors-in-computer-vision)